# Pandas/matplotlib line plot does not show x axis text labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Issue**

Plotting data from a DataFrame into a line plot excludes "dates" on the x axis.

```
north_result = list(data.aggregate(pipeline))

dates =['Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
north_result_df = pd.DataFrame(north_result, index=dates)
north_result_df.index.name = 'Months'
north_result_df.plot.line()
```

[image]

Line plot requires dates just above 'months' on the x axis. Dates show if they are numeric and not strings...any help would be greatly appreciated! As you can tell i am pretty new to Pandas...

**Solution**

```
north_result = list(data.aggregate(pipeline))

dates =['Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
north_result_df = pd.DataFrame(north_result, index=dates)
north_result_df.index.name = 'Months'
plt.plot(north_result_df.index, north_result_df["total"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which version of pandas? In my 0.24.1 it works and looks as expected.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22334) is still not fixed.

Comment: Great....anyway around it Ernest?

Comment: My suggestion would be the same as the answer below: use matplotlib directly instead.

Comment: Thanks however I am getting an error using the proposed solution (shown in comments)

Comment: I have no idea what `list(data.aggregate(pipeline))` does. But if you have a usual dataframe with numerical values in a column and a normal index (no multiindex, no PeriodIndex) you can use `plt.plot(df.index, df["column"])`.

Comment: Excellent that's got it thank you. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pyplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
north_result =[5,6,7,2,8,5,4,8,9,4,1,5]
dates =['Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
north_result_df = pd.DataFrame(north_result, index=dates)
north_result_df.index.name = 'Months'
plt.plot(north_result_df)
plt.show()
```

the result will be like:

[image]

Comment: Cheers however I now get - TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' - north_result_df is declared as follows = north_result = list(street.aggregate(pipeline))

Comment: Final solution added to question